# "Code Reformatting" feature for a whole project by using ReSharper

Tags: resharper

I like **ReSharper** *"Code Reformatting"* feature and I often use it for a single file, but is it possible to reformat code for a whole project by using **ReSharper**?

Comment: Make sure the project is selected in solution explorer, then run the cleanup code as normal.  It will say, "Clean up code in project Foo".

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Right click on project in solution explorer - "Cleanup Code..." menu item.